# Swagger-ui how is the name of api (resource) generated?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

When I create an API with swagger, normaly my API has the name of the resource:

```
Tasks
/tasks
/tasks/{id}
etc.
```

Sometimes I only get a default:

```
Default
GET /tasks
GET /tasks/{uuid}
etc.
```

What determines the header name of the API generated?

Screenshot of wished behaviour (tasks is sometimes default):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean these headers in Swagger UI?

[image: headers]

They are generated based on the `tags` of your API operations. For example, to group operations under "Tasks", use:

```
{
  ...

  "paths": {
    "\/tasks:": {
       "tags": [
         "Tasks"
       ],
       ...
```

Each operation can have any number of tags. Operations with no tags will be listed under the "Default" group.

To provide description for the tags, use the top-level `tags` section:

```
{
  ...

  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Tasks",
      "description": "Operations to manage tasks"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Notes",
      "description": "Operations to manage notes"
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you have passed on as an argument to swagger's Api annotation (`io.swagger.annotations.Api`) at the top of your RESTful service implementation -

```
@Path(value="/")
@Api(value="/")
public interface YourService {
    ....
}
```

`@Api(value="/")` will generate `default`

`@Api(value="/Tasks")` will generate `Tasks`